# Количество элементов в двумерном массиве

Tags: php

Пытаюсь вывести кол-во элементов в массиве $B_cases, но все время выводит 0, что я не так сделал?

```
$str = 'B';

$B_cases = array(
    0 => array('A1' =>'a1'), 
    1 => array('A2' =>'a2'),
    2 => array('A3' => 'a3'), 
    3 => array('A4' =>'a4'));

    $list_cases = array('A' => $A_cases, 'B' => $B_cases, 'C' => $C_cases);

    echo count($list_case[$str]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что `list_cases`, а не `list_case`

---

на будущее: напиши `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ([error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php)) в начале страницы, чтобы тебе отображались все ошибки!

В данном случае вылетела бы ошибка:

> **E_NOTICE** : type 8 -- Undefined variable: list_case -- at line 12

---

Еще полезное чтиво: **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)**

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @ByArper Еще полезное чтиво: **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)**  .... можешь галку ставить)